# Overwrite app and deletes database on Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am creating multiple apps and every app has same package so if I install one then it should overwrite the other, i.e. one of these apps can only be installed in the phone. This may sound weird but this is the way apps need to be. I have all the apps ready but I have this issue that I want to drop the table of database on every install, so if I install second app it overwrites the first one but the database is not deleted. I cannot change the VersionCode as I won't be able to overwrite with the older version so all apps have same package and same version code.

Basically it should ask for a password on every first run of the app, then I create a table and store it there that this user is authenticated, so for every new app this has to be done again but on update the table remains there which results in no prompt for password. Now how do i detect and drop the table from database. Even if I use sharedpreferences instead of database, they remain there on the update and I can't even detect if the app is updated as version code is same.

I will really appreciate if anyone can give me a solution or a hint.

Thank you,

Hamza Manzoor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store a seperate version value of the apps in the SharedPreferences and check the value in it against a list or numerical value and decide depending on the result.
You could also use Android's built-in version (not the nummrical value but the string value).

If you go for the SharedPreferences solution, you can use a kind of algorithm for the version value. Let's say one app is numbered "A", another "B" and yet another "C". You then append the app's real version to that, i.e. "A1.0" or "B2.4", ... (you get the idea). This way Android has no idea of what app is curretly being installed.

Whenever you start an app just check for the first value. If that is different from the app's normal value you know, it has been replaced. Otherwise check for the version value and see, whether you need to update the database or not.

// May I add:
Of course this is a possible source for bugs but if you are careful this should work. If someone has a better solution, please post.

Answer (score 1):

Your app will not be overwritten\upgraded via Google Play mechanism in case they will have the same versionCode. Only via "adb install -rd" or some root-enabled side-loader.

IMHO, the right way to act is

- increase versionCode and DB SCHEMA_VERSION on each upgrade as usual
- in your DB class (which extends SQLiteOpenHelper) in onUpgrade() method you should check DB version and set some variable in Prefs accordingly, later in Activity you'll be able to fire a password dialog (open DB on onCreate(), check prefs on onResume()).

Comment: The apps are obviously not on google play otherwise I wouldve to change package name and version code, if I change version code then I wont be able to overwrite higher version code with the lower one